# Are international flights from/to Istanbul Atatürk Airport empty?

Tags: international-travel, event-based-effects, isl

After the attack on Istanbul Atatürk Airport, are international flights leaving from or going to there currently relatively empty?

Comment: If there aren't enough people, airlines won't fly empty planes. Your question is rather broad, is there a source you're more interested in ?

Comment: a source I am interested in? I thought that maybe they still fly them for now to not get a wrong idea in people's heads until the dust is settled

Comment: A travel source to Istanbul (ie from Kabul or Paris). You can be sure airlines wouldn't risk losing money to try to contain panic

Comment: Why are you asking this now? Unless there has been an attack in the past 6 hours, this question is outdated.